# Java - Scanning comma delimited double and int values

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I'm trying to use Java's Scanner class to scan in double and int values delimited by commas.

The following `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\D");` can only scan int values separated by `,`. e.g. input = `1000,2,3`

How do I scan in double and int values separated by `,` e.g. input = `1000.00,3.25,5` or `100.00,2,3.5`?

I tried the following but they don't seem to work:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(",");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\,");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("[,]");
```

Using these seems to hang the code. After entering the example input, System.out.println did not execute for the scanned in variables.

Below is my sample code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
  public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    System.out.print("Enter your values: ");
    // Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\D");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(",");
    // Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\,");
    // Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("[,]");

    double investmentAmount = input.nextDouble();
    double monthlyInterestRate = input.nextDouble() / 100 / 12;
    double numberOfYears = input.nextDouble();
    double duration = numberOfYears * 12;

    double futureInvestmentValue = investmentAmount * Math.pow((1 + monthlyInterestRate), duration);
    System.out.println(investmentAmount);
    System.out.println(monthlyInterestRate);
    System.out.println(numberOfYears);
    System.out.println(duration);
    System.out.println("Accumulated value is " + futureInvestmentValue);
  }
}
```

**Solution found**

Updating the Scanner line to the following seem to have fixed it:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("[,\n]");
```

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. What's your input and output?

Comment: @4castle, my input is `1000.00,3.25,1` all on one line as one input. There's no output as the code hangs after entering the input. I'm on OpenJDK Java 7

Comment: @eduardo-dennis I would if the code works. It still hangs with `input.nextLine();` as how you coded it after the last nextDouble() and entering `1000.00,3.25,1` as the input all on one line.

Comment: @j7an copy and paste my exact code it works just as expected.

Comment: @eduardo-dennis I've done that already

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you have `Locale` issues and your `Scanner` tries to parse doubles with comma delimeter, but you set comma as a scanner delimeter. Try the following solution:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)
        .useDelimiter(",")
        .useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

This will set doubles delimiter to dot and your comma-separated doubles should work fine.

Be sure to place the comma at the end of input to parse the last value, e.g. `1000.00,3.25,5,` (may be even it is the primary reason of your inputs not working)

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out. Having the input end with comma works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you faced is because nextDouble() doesn't consume the last line. Try adding an input.nextLine() at the end it should work as expected.

```
   /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
System.out.print("Enter your values: ");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(",");

double investmentAmount = input.nextDouble();
double monthlyInterestRate = input.nextDouble() / 100 / 12;
double numberOfYears = input.nextDouble();
input.nextLine();
double duration = numberOfYears * 12;

double futureInvestmentValue = investmentAmount * Math.pow((1 + monthlyInterestRate), duration);
System.out.println(investmentAmount);
System.out.println(monthlyInterestRate);
System.out.println(numberOfYears);
System.out.println(duration);
System.out.println("Accumulated value is " + futureInvestmentValue);
```

[Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/1754020)

Comment: Yes, I must accept all the input on online. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: I just realized you ended your input with a comma. I tried that and it worked. If I don't end the input with a comma. It won't work.

Comment: @j7an check my edit. You can add an input.nextLine() to fix that issue.

Comment: I've added `String x = input.nextLine();` below the last nextDouble() and it still hangs. The issue is that useDelimiter needs to delimit both the comma and the carriage return "[,\n]"

Comment: I added the code, it is working for me without the need of the last ,.